# Take derivative of matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

A part of an objective function is:

$$F=\|H-\mu_H\|_F^2$$

And we have:

$$\mu_H=\frac{\Sigma H}{n_H}$$

In fact, $\mu_H$ is the average of $H$ in one dimension and is repeated $n$ times in which all columns are the same.

How can I take the derivative of $F$ with respect to $H$ i.e. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial H}$?

Comment: In other words, you are asking for the derivative of the norm of the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be written as $F(H) = f(g(H))$, where
$$
f(H) = \|H\|_F^2, \quad g(H) = H - \mu_H = H - \frac 1n Hee^T
$$
where $e = (1,\dots,1)^T$. The [total derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of these functions are given by
$$
df(H)(K) = 2\operatorname{Tr}(H^TK), \quad dg(H)(K) = g(K).
$$
With the chain rule, we have
$$
d(f \circ g)(H)(K) = [df(H) \circ dg(H)](K)\\
= df(H)(g(K)) = df(H)\left(K - \frac 1n Kee^T\right)\\
= 2\operatorname{Tr}\left( H^T\left(K - \frac 1n Kee^T\right)\right)\\
= 2\operatorname{Tr}(H^TK) - \frac 2n\operatorname{Tr}((Hee^T)^TK)\\
= 2 \operatorname{Tr}\left( \left(H - \frac 1n Hee^T \right)^TK\right)\\
= 2 \operatorname{Tr}(g(H)^TK)
$$
In ["denominator layout"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix), this derivative is given by $\frac{\partial F}{\partial H} = 2g(H)$.

Comment: What is $K$ here?

Comment: $K$ is a matrix of the same shape as $H$. As the wikipedia page explains, the derivative at $H$, $df(H)$, is a linear map that takes in a matrix and produces a matrix; $K$ is the input to this function. An equivalent way to think about it is the following: for any matrix $K$, $df(H)(K)$ is the "directional derivative" along $K$.

Comment: So what are the values of this matrix? How can I calculate it?

Comment: @M As I say in the last line, the matrix of the denominator-layout derivative is given by $2g(H) = 2(H - \mu_H)$.

Answer (score 0):

The [Centering Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix) is an idempotent matrix which can be defined in terms of the identity matrix $(I)$ and all-ones matrix $(J)$ as
$$\eqalign{
C &= I - \tfrac 1nJ, \qquad
C^2 &= C = C^T \\
}$$
Define the matrix variable $Y$ as
$$\eqalign{
Y &= HC \;=\; (H-\mu_H) \\
YC &= HC^2 \;=\; HC = Y \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
Rewriting the objective function using $Y$ makes it easier to differentiate
$$\eqalign{
\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}
\def\p{\partial}
F &= \|Y\|^2_F \;=\; Y:Y \\
dF &= 2Y:dY = 2Y:(dH\,C) = 2(YC):dH = 2Y:dH \\
\frac{\p F}{\p H} &= 2Y \;=\; 2(H-\mu_H) \\\\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \tr(A^TB) \;=\; B:A \\
A:A &= \tr(A^TA) \;=\; \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$